# Check record based on criteria in multiple related records

Tags: ms-access, vba

Let me start with the structure.

I have a `Class` that has many `Experiences`.

The `Class` can only be cleared if all the `Experiences` have been cleared.

The `Class` and `Experience` share an `Experence_ID` This ID is not unique to an `Experience`.

For example, if I run `'DoCmd.OpenForm "Experences", , , "[Experence ID] = '" & Me.Experence_ID'` from the 'Class' I can get more than one record.

What script could I use to check if the `Experence_Cleared` is checked (it is a checkbox field) in each `Experience` record that has the same `Experence_ID` as the `Class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later I found out that I needed more data from each record. I used the following code to obtain it.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim i As Integer

Dim Hours As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Experiences")

For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
    If rs.Fields("Experience ID") = Experience_ID And rs.Fields("Primary") <> 0 And rs.Fields("Experience Clear") Then
        Hours = Hours + rs.Fields("Hours")
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Next i

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
```

I was then able to use the `hours` to determine if my class was ready to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check that a Bit/Boolean field in a table is true for each record with field `Experence_ID` matching an input value.

In that case, you could use:

```
If DCount("*","tblYourTableNameHere","[Experence Cleared]=0 AND [Experence ID]=" & Me.Experence_ID) > 0 Then
    Msgbox "There are some Experiences that have not been cleared for this Class"
Else
    Msgbox "All Experiences have been cleared for this Class!"
End If
```

The code above uses the DCount() function to count the amount of records that match the qualifiers in the final argument. So it will only count rows in the table that have the `[Experence Cleared]` field as `FALSE` AS WELL AS having the `[Experence ID]` field equaling the value of the `Me.Experence_ID` field on the form. If it returns a count greater than zero, then not all 'Experiences' are 'cleared'.

I have had to make some assumptions about control and field names, be sure to modify this code to suit, or give me more information and I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get records from `Class` for which all `Experiences` have been cleared, you can use a [subquery](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Class]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ExperienceID
    FROM Experiences
    WHERE [Class].ExperienceID = Experiences.ExperienceID
        AND NOT Experience_Cleared
)
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx) (with [`DISTINCTROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx) to stop the rows in `Class` from being repeated for each corresponding record in `Experiences`):

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Class].*
FROM [Class]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ExperienceID
    FROM Experiences
    WHERE NOT Experience_Cleared
) AS t1 ON Class.ExperienceID = t1.ExperienceID
WHERE t1.ExperienceID IS NULL
```

In either case, you can check if a specific class exists in these records with an additional `WHERE` predicate:

```
    AND ClassID = [Replace with ClassID expression]
```